# Add persistance on bootable flashdrive from the bootable flashdrive

Tags: usb-drive, persistence

I am currently booted from Ubuntu on a flash drive.
However, it doesn't have persistence. Is there a way to give it persistence while booted on it without reinstalling it?
I don't have admin on the machine I am booting from, so I can't actually reinstall a version with persistence.

I'm using vanilla Ubuntu downloaded from the website yesterday. I installed it with rufus.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is trivial to add.

Add a casper-rw . https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence#Creating_the_.22casper-rw.22_File_System

This can be on your hard drive or usb. If needed resize your usb partition and add  a second with the file.

To use it is a boot option. Hit F6 and add it in

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence#Booting_the_Live_CD_in_Persistent_Mode

Comment: I tried this and now I can't boot windows...

Comment: It also didn't work

Comment: What did you do ? Making these changes should not have affected windows at all.

Comment: I booted linux from my flash drive and followed the steps given in the link you sent

Comment: what commands did you run ?

Comment: `df -h` `sudo umount /dev/sda1` `sudo mkfs.ext3 -b 4096 -L casper-rw /dev/sda1` `if=/dev/zero of=/media/hda1/casper-rw bs=1M count=1` `mkfs.ext3 /media/hda1/casper-rw`

Comment: So what used to be on sda1 and hda1 ?

Comment: I'm not sure....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65617/discussion-between-bodhi-zazen-and-10-replies).